# WordPress sub-menu left margin

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using 2013 theme on wordpress release 4.1 and facing some issue with the main menu. In the sub-menus there is around 40px left margin which I don't want. I could not figure it out how to eliminate the left margin on sub-menus. Site is http://aapina.org/wp/

Thanks

Comment: So go into your code,its probably a pure css menu,just edit the width.

Comment: I edited the width but still there is left margin on the sub menus

Comment: if its left margin then do something like margin-left:0 !important;

Comment: I put margin:0 !important;   padding:0 !important;  but still there is a margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's default padding on the ul element. You can remove it like:

```
.sub-menu { padding-left: 0; }
```

or set it to anything you want.

Comment: Thanks  I put .sub-menu { padding-left: 0; }

Comment: using padding-X or margin-X is bad practice. It's better to incorporate the lower load of padding: X X X X instead.

Comment: It is not bad practice. Specifying the single change you want retains the other values, which may be set by multiple other selectors. Specifying all of the values means that you have to know what they all are and know that they will not change (or else remember to come back to this rule and change it if they do change).

Answer (score 1):

```
**User Agent Stylesheet**
ul, menu, dir {
display: block;
list-style-type: disc;
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
-webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
```

This is your issue. Make sure to CSS reset your style sheet. However, specifically for this.

```
.sub-menu {padding:0 0 0 2rem};
```

Comment: Thanks  I put .sub-menu { padding-left: 0; }

Comment: @Paramasivan Don't do that. It's bad and unprofessional.

Comment: Thanks !  I did .sub-menu { padding: 0; }